# SQL Server 2014 - Multiple SUM/COUNT with subqueries

Tags: sql-server, join, count, subquery

I have a two part question.

**First part** is about the speed of what I am doing below. I am taking a data set and getting each `DISTINCT`, then joining a subquery that sums/counts with criteria, then repeating that five times. After the first `LEFT JOIN` I have a run time of 02 seconds, after the second `LEFT JOIN` I have a run time of 04 seconds, but on the third `LEFT JOIN` my run time goes to 44 seconds. If that pull that query aside and run it alone, it is just 01 second. The total run time for the finished query is 70 seconds.

**First part question:**

What is making this query dramatically slower at the third join?

**Second part**: I am sure that I am accomplishing this in an inefficient way. I looked around for a while and was unable to find a way to accomplish what I am doing in a simple way while still being able to have different criteria for each subquery.

**Second part question:**

Is there a better way of accomplishing this query?

**Edit** after user1413's comment.

`SELECT DISTINCT` at the beginning was showing 49% cost in SQL Server execution plan view. I changed the table that the `SELECT DISTINCT` was selecting from and my run time went down to below 01 second.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    od.location, currentTires, currentAlignments, currentLubes, 
    currentBatteries,currentSiping,currentCarcount
FROM 
    comm.dbo.ordetail as od
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         od2.location, SUM(od2.qty_shipped) as currentTires
     FROM 
         comm.dbo.ordetail as od2
     JOIN 
         comm.dbo.invmas as invmas2 ON invmas2.item_num = od2.item#
     JOIN 
         comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh2 ON oh2.location = od2.location
                                AND oh2.inv_date = od2.inv_date
                                AND oh2.invoice# = od2.invoice#
     WHERE 
         (oh2.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh2.type_of_rec = '02')
         AND od2.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
         AND od2.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
         AND ( invmas2.category = 'uhp' OR invmas2.category = 'tour' OR invmas2.category = 'mass' OR invmas2.category = 'suv' OR invmas2.category = 'ltat' OR invmas2.category = 'ltmt' OR invmas2.category = 'lthwy' OR invmas2.category = 'snow' OR invmas2.category = 'stdls' )
    GROUP BY 
        od2.location) as currentTires ON od.location = currentTires.location
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         od3.location, SUM(od3.qty_shipped) as currentAlignments
     FROM 
         comm.dbo.ordetail as od3
     JOIN 
         comm.dbo.invmas as invmas3 ON invmas3.item_num = od3.item#
     JOIN 
         comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh3 ON oh3.location = od3.location
                                AND oh3.inv_date = od3.inv_date
                                AND oh3.invoice# = od3.invoice#
     WHERE 
         (oh3.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh3.type_of_rec = '02')
         AND od3.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
         AND od3.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
         AND (od3.item# = '8501' OR od3.item# = '8502')
     GROUP BY 
         od3.location) as currentAlignments ON od.location = currentAlignments.location
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         od4.location, SUM(od4.qty_shipped) as currentLubes
     FROM 
         comm.dbo.ordetail as od4
     JOIN 
         comm.dbo.invmas as invmas4 ON invmas4.item_num = od4.item#
     JOIN 
         comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh4 ON oh4.location = od4.location
                                AND oh4.inv_date = od4.inv_date
                                AND oh4.invoice# = od4.invoice#
     WHERE 
         (oh4.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh4.type_of_rec = '02')
         AND od4.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
         AND od4.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
         AND (od4.item# = '200fs' OR od4.item# = '200c' OR od4.item# = '200m' OR od4.item# = '200s')
     GROUP BY 
         od4.location) as currentLubes ON od.location = currentLubes.location
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT od5.location,SUM(od5.qty_shipped) as currentBatteries
        FROM comm.dbo.ordetail as od5
        JOIN comm.dbo.invmas as invmas5
            ON invmas5.item_num = od5.item#
        JOIN comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh5
            ON oh5.location = od5.location
            AND oh5.inv_date = od5.inv_date
            AND oh5.invoice# = od5.invoice#
        WHERE ( oh5.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh5.type_of_rec = '02' )
            AND od5.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
            AND od5.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
            AND invmas5.manufact = 'inter'
        GROUP BY od5.location) as currentBatteries
        ON od.location = currentBatteries.location
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT od6.location,SUM(od6.qty_shipped) as currentSiping
        FROM comm.dbo.ordetail as od6
        JOIN comm.dbo.invmas as invmas6
            ON invmas6.item_num = od6.item#
        JOIN comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh6
            ON oh6.location = od6.location
            AND oh6.inv_date = od6.inv_date
            AND oh6.invoice# = od6.invoice#
        WHERE ( oh6.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh6.type_of_rec = '02' )
            AND od6.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
            AND od6.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
            AND invmas6.manufact = 'inter'
        GROUP BY od6.location) as currentSiping
        ON od.location = currentSiping.location
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT od7.location,COUNT(DISTINCT oh7.invoice#) as currentCarcount
        FROM comm.dbo.ordetail as od7
        JOIN comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh7
            ON oh7.location = od7.location
            AND oh7.inv_date = od7.inv_date
            AND oh7.invoice# = od7.invoice#
        WHERE ( oh7.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh7.type_of_rec = '02' )
            AND od7.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
            AND od7.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
            AND oh7.veh_make != ''
            AND od7.item# != ''
        GROUP BY od7.location) as currentCarcount
        ON od.location = currentCarcount.location
    ORDER BY od.location
```

Sample data output:

[image]

Comment: did you checked the execution plan?

Comment: I just did, I am unfamiliar with what I am looking at. Not an easy way to share it. Lots of data. XML output is 5k lines. Should I be identifying high cost operations and find ways to reduce them?

Comment: I didn't meant that one. There is a icon in SSMS. You can even find that in Query Menu --> Display Estimated Execution Plan that will help you where it is taking more time based on percentage shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things that could be made better here. For starters, one of the following joins below could be eliminated as the same items are returned for both od5 and od6.

```
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT od5.location,SUM(od5.qty_shipped) as currentBatteries
    FROM comm.dbo.ordetail as od5
    JOIN comm.dbo.invmas as invmas5
        ON invmas5.item_num = od5.item#
    JOIN comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh5
        ON oh5.location = od5.location
        AND oh5.inv_date = od5.inv_date
        AND oh5.invoice# = od5.invoice#
    WHERE ( oh5.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh5.type_of_rec = '02' )
        AND od5.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND od5.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
        AND invmas5.manufact = 'inter'
    GROUP BY od5.location) as currentBatteries
    ON od.location = currentBatteries.location
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT od6.location,SUM(od6.qty_shipped) as currentSiping
    FROM comm.dbo.ordetail as od6
    JOIN comm.dbo.invmas as invmas6
        ON invmas6.item_num = od6.item#
    JOIN comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh6
        ON oh6.location = od6.location
        AND oh6.inv_date = od6.inv_date
        AND oh6.invoice# = od6.invoice#
    WHERE ( oh6.type_of_rec = '01' OR oh6.type_of_rec = '02' )
        AND od6.inv_date >= '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND od6.inv_date <= '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
        AND invmas6.manufact = 'inter'
    GROUP BY od6.location) as currentSiping
    ON od.location = currentSiping.location
```

As for performance and readability try something like below. NOTE : I can not possibly test this, however, it may give insight to someone with more time to fiddle with performance tuning your query.

```
DECLARE @LowDate DATETIME = '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @HighDate DATETIME = '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'


SELECT
    DetailList.location,
    currentTires = SUM(currentTires), 
    currentAlignments = SUM(currentAlignments),
    currentLubes = SUM(currentLubes),
    currentBatteries = SUM(currentBatteries),
    currentSiping = SUM(currentSiping),         
    carCount = SUM(hasCar)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        od.location,
        currentLubes=CASE WHEN  ( od.item# = '200fs' OR od.item# = '200c' OR od.item# = '200m' OR od.item# = '200s' ) THEN od.qty_shipped ELSE NULL END,
        currentAlignments=CASE WHEN  ( od.item# = '8501' OR od.item# = '8502' ) THEN od.qty_shipped ELSE NULL END,
        currentSiping = CASE WHEN ( invmas.item_num = 'p15' OR invmas.item_num = 'u15' ) THEN od.qty_shipped ELSE NULL END,
        currentBatteries = CASE WHEN invmas.manufact = 'inter' THEN od.qty_shipped ELSE NULL END,
        currentTires=  CASE WHEN ( invmas.category = 'uhp' OR invmas.category = 'tour' OR invmas.category = 'mass' OR invmas.category = 'suv' OR invmas.category = 'ltat' OR 
                    invmas.category = 'ltmt' OR invmas.category = 'lthwy' OR invmas.category = 'snow' OR invmas.category = 'stdls' ) THEN od.qty_shipped ELSE NULL END,
    hasCar= CASE WHEN (oh.veh_make != '' AND od.item# !='') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        comm.dbo.ordetail as od
        LEFT JOIN comm.dbo.invmas as invmas ON invmas.item_num = od.item# --FOR currentCarcount
        INNER JOIN comm.dbo.ordhrd as oh ON oh.location = od.location AND oh.inv_date = od.inv_date AND oh.invoice# = od.invoice#
    WHERE
        od.inv_date BETWEEN '2017-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-02-28 00:00:00.000'
        AND
        oh.type_of_rec IN('01','02')
)AS DetailList
GROUP BY
    DetailList.location
```

Comment: I had to make a couple changes to get it to work. The two `CASE WHEN` that were the same was a mistake from me. I fixed those. Data set is complete and this runs with a sub 01 second run time. Thanks a lot for taking your time to provide me with an answer.

Comment: Glad I could help.